# How to config kafka broker for quickly retention?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using the Kafka cluster.

I want design for the broker to keep the message only 1 seconds.

So,
I want to kafka config to like below

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
default.replication.factor=3
min.insync.replicas=2
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=2
replica.lag.time.max.ms=10000
##replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
#log.cleanup.policy=delete
#log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=1000
log.flush.interval.ms=1000
log.retention.ms=1000
```

But, the consumer still got a old message (the message produced before 1 second more)

test command

./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092, --topic test-topic --from-beginning

How do I config the broker? to keep the message only 1 second